# Divergence of Harmonic Series with a random variable

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have a random series of events $X_0, X_1, \ldots$ with probabilities $P(X_0), P(X_1), \ldots$ for which $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} P(X_n) = 1$ (could be a the event that random samples will fall into a certain region of a space).

Right now, I try to investigate the behavior of
$$
\begin{equation}
\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n} \frac{P(X_j)}{j}
\end{equation}
$$

I believe this series to be divergent since it closely resembles the harmonic series (for which we know that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n} \frac{1}{j} = \infty$). If this is true, how could I prove it?

Comment: @runway44 In the original version  we were given that $\sum P(X_j)<\infty$. That got edited out between the time I posted my comment and the time you saw it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're wondering about $\sum p_k/k$ where $p_k$ is a sequence tending to $p_k\to 1$ in the limit.

The limit means that given any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $|p_k-1|<\varepsilon$. In particular, if we pick $0<\varepsilon<1$, this forces $p_k>1-\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$. Then

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{p_k}{k}>\sum_{k=1}^N \frac{p_k}{k}+\sum_{k=N+1}^\infty\frac{1-\varepsilon}{k} $$

The last sum above is a constant multiple of the harmonic series with finitely many terms removed, so it diverges, which means the original series diverges.